# Функция перебора последовательности ("XXXXYYYYZZZZZ")

Tags: javascript

Есть последовательность ('XXXXYYYYZZZZZ') нужно разбить её на не повторяющиеся символы и засунуть в массив. Что бы получилось ['X', 'Y', 'Z'].

```
function uniqueInOrder(iterable){
  console.log(Array.from(iterable).filter((v, i, a) => v != a[i - 1]));
}
uniqueInOrder();
```

Почему undefined, помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: `console.log( "XXXXYYYYZZZZZaFF".match(/(.)\1*/g).map( e => e[0] ) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что строку надо туда передать.

```js
function uniqueInOrder(iterable){
  console.log(Array.from(iterable).filter((v, i, a) => v != a[i - 1]));
} 

uniqueInOrder('XXXXYYYYZZZZZ');
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно лениво и непроизводительно, но зато читаемо - через `Set`:

```js
function uniqueInOrder(iterable) {
  console.log(Array.from(new Set([...iterable])));
} 

uniqueInOrder('XXXXYYYYZZZZZ');
```